# Saxon XSLT 2.0 and RFC 822 date format

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, rfc822, xpath-2.0

What is the right way to format xs:dateTime to RFC 822?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [fn:format-dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-format-dateTime)

I think it should be:

```
format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),
                '[FNn,*-3], [D01] [MNn,*-3] [Y0001] [H01]:[m01]:[s01] [Z]',
                'en',
                '',
                'US')
```

Right now, for me, output:

```
Thu, 07 Oct 2010 21:10:03 -03:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup.  I added 'AD' as the calendar and that cleaned up the output using SaxonHE 9.3.0.5

```
fn:format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),
            '[FNn,*-3], [D01] [MNn,*-3] [Y0001] [H01]:[m01]:[s01] [Z]',
            'en',
            'AD',
            'US')
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(ms:format-date(InputDate, 'ddd, dd MMM yyyy'), ' ', ms:format-time(InputDate, 'HH:mm:ss'), ' EST')"/>
```

When date was retrieved from database as:

```
 SELECT
      Table.DateField AS InputDate
    FROM Table
```

or try : 
     SELECT
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Table.DateField, 101) AS InputDate
    FROM Table